# How to split a large text file in to smaller files with equal number of lines using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

i've got a large (by number of lines) plain text file that I'd like to split into smaller files, also by number of lines. So if my file has around 2M lines, I'd like to split it up into 10 files that contain 200k lines, or 100 files that contain 20k lines (plus one file with the remainder; being evenly divisible doesn't matter).

I found the following code online but it takes some time and it´s not the most efficient way, anyway can anyone help on another way for me to do this ?

```
ReDim outputlines(maxRows - 1) As String
p = InStrRev(inputFile, ".")
part = 0
n = 0

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TSRead = FSO.OpenTextFile(inputFile)

While Not TSRead.AtEndOfStream
    outputlines(n) = TSRead.ReadLine
    n = n + 1

    If n = maxRows Then
        part = part + 1
        outputFile = Left(inputFile, p - 1) & " PART" & part & Mid(inputFile, p) & " .csv"
        Set TSWrite = FSO.CreateTextFile(outputFile, True)
        TSWrite.Write Join(outputlines, vbCrLf)
        TSWrite.Close
        ReDim outputlines(maxRows - 1) As String
        n = 0
        ' Set wb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile, 0, True, 5)
        'wb.Activate
        'MEF
        'wb.Close (False)
    End If
Wend

TSRead.Close

If n > 0 Then
    ReDim outputlines2(n - 1) As String

    For i = 0 To n - 1
        outputlines2(i) = outputlines(i)
    Next

    part = part + 1
    outputFile = Left(inputFile, p - 1) & " PART" & part & Mid(inputFile, p) & " .csv"

    Set TSWrite = FSO.CreateTextFile(outputFile, True)
    TSWrite.Write Join(outputlines2, vbCrLf)
    TSWrite.Close

    ' Set wb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile, 0, True, 5)
    'wb.Activate
    'MEF
    'wb.Close (False)
End If

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you must use VBA?  If this is a text file, seems to me you'd be significantly better off with a shell script solution.  Also, we have no idea how the decision will be made regarding number of files and number of lines.  Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I´m forced to use vba.

Comment: I want the user to insert a certain number of lines and then the original file with 1 000 000 lines will be splited in to a new smaller file with like per e.g. 200 000 lines until there are no more lines left

Comment: Like og file = 1 000 000    and it´s suposed to create 6 new files with 200 000 each except for the last one

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the array as a "middleman" altogether.  Please see the following solution, which avoids that.  It should (WARNING: untested) read each line of the input file, and write to consecutive output files, creating new output files as it progresses.  I created the function BuildOutputName() because it is an excellent practice to avoid repeating code.

I must admit, I really didn't follow your purpose to writing to the output file twice, but that's a moot point since this replaces that solution.

```
Function BuildOutputName(inputName as string, partNumber as integer) as String
    ' Using the Part Number, build a new filename based on the original filename.
    p = InStrRev(inputFile, ".")
    Return Left(inputFile, p - 1) & " PART" & part & Mid(inputFile, p) & ".csv"
End Function


ReDim outputlines(maxRows - 1) As String
p = InStrRev(inputFile, ".")
part = 1
n = 0

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TSRead = FSO.OpenTextFile(inputFile)
OutputFile = BuildOutputName(inputFile, Part)
Set TSWrite = FSO.CreateTextFile(outputFile, True)

While Not TSRead.AtEndOfStream
    outputline = TSRead.ReadLine
    n = n + 1
    If n > maxRows Then
        ' This line would cause us to exceed our maximum.  Close the current output
        ' file, and create a new one.  This will be our first line in that file.
        TSWrite.Close
        part = part + 1
        outputFile = BuildOutputName(inputFile, Part)
        Set TSWrite = FSO.CreateTextFile(outputFile, True)
        n = 0
    End If
    TSWrite.Write outputline + vbCrLf
Wend
TSWrite.Close
TSRead.Close

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: Thank you mate, just tell me something pls. do you know what can I do in order for those smaller splited to be created in excel type file ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by “Excel type file.”  CSV?  CSV is about format, and this proess doesn’t change format.  Do you want it to?